# Finding the first row that meets conditions of a mask starting from nth row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

This is my dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 100, 4, 100, 20], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]})
```

I want to create column `c` by using a mask. This is my desired output:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  100  20  NaN
3    4  20  NaN
4  100  20  x
5   20  20  NaN
```

My mask is:

```py
mask = (df.a > df.b)
```

Note that I want to start looking for this mask from the third row. That is, rows 0, 1 and 2 do not count. That is why the first row that meets the `a` > `b` is the 5th row which its index is 4.

This is what I have tried. But I don't know how to start from the third row.

```py
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

These are some additional examples. First three rows do not count.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust solution that works independently of the index and if there is no match in the mask:

```
# original mask
mask = (df.a > df.b)

# set first n values to False
mask &= np.arange(len(df)) > 2

# only keep first True (if any)
mask &= ~mask.duplicated()

df.loc[mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

Output:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  100  20  NaN
3    4  20  NaN
4  100  20    x
5   20  20  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 100, 4, 100, 20], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]})

# Create a mask starting from the third row
mask = (df['a'] > df['b']).iloc[2:]

# Use the modified mask to assign 'x' to column 'c'
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'

print(df)
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  100  20  NaN
3    4  20  NaN
4  100  20    x
5   20  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another mask for the index (which only starts flagging from the third row) and chain it with the mask for the comparison.

```py
msk1 = df['a'] > df['b']
msk2 = df.index > 2
df.loc[(msk1 & msk2).idxmax(), 'c'] = 'x'
```

which creates the desired output:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20  NaN
2  100  20  NaN
3    4  20  NaN
4  100  20    x
5   20  20  NaN
```

Another option is to create a new column (using a `mask()` call) from scratch and assign it.

```py
mask = df.eval("a > b and index > 2").cumsum().eq(1)
df['c'] = pd.Series(index=df.index).mask(mask, 'x')
```